# I'm trying to create a Multiple choice quiz in c#/winforms, using sql to store retrieve the questions

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I wish to create a simple Winforms app that can access questions from a SQL table called "questions table" as well as table called "answersTable". I would then like to assign the question result to a single textbox on screen and have the 3 "answersTable" results be mapped to 3 individual buttons, I have already made all the forms and achieved this using a JOIN query to join my tables and then mapping the controls (by mapping the controls via the `dataReader`,

i.e

```
while data.read()
{ 
    button1.text = datareader.getValue(0) 
};
```

[my Winforms which I wish to populate from SQL tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLi5t.png)

[My code to populate the Winforms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tKzR.png)

[This is what I would like to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCwuc.png)

However this only works for the last question and answer in the table and gives me no control of displaying the previous or next entry in the questions and answers tables.

My next thought was to try and take the data from the SQL tables add them to a list box and then use the list box to map the questions and answers to my forms controls but am just unsure if this is the best way to go about it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot going on with this code. Let me start with your problem and continue with the rest.

1. The load method. My guess is what you call in the on initialization of the form. You are reading until the last value from the reader and never look back. What you could do instead.

Create a new class `QuizQuestion` which will depict your database return structure.

```
pubic class QuizQuestion {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }
     // continue for the rest
}
```

Now in your class,  create a member

```
List<QuizQuestion> quizQuestions;
```

And last in your while datareader clause,  create one QuizQuestion object for every row and add it to your list.

This way you will have all the values saved. Now create a function that will get the last index and show the right list item.

Also create an event for each button to use the previous function to go to the next answer.

2. Don't forget to close the connection object you are creating. Check the keyword `using`

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment, i am new to c# and am having trouble understanding how i would use                                                                              
    pubic class QuizQuestion {
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string AnswerA { get; set; }
    
}                                                                                                                                             to get the values from the SQL table, could you please elaborate on this